# RotWord in Rijndael's Algorithm

Tags: rijndael

I am currently learning Rijndael's Algorithm through [this site](http://formaestudio.com/rijndaelinspector/archivos/rijndaelanimation.html) where there is a slide show animation step-by-step.
I understand nearly all of the encryption process except part of *Add Round Key*.
Looking at slides 16 & 17, it says:

> > Applying the **RotWord** ... to the previous word **Wi-1**

What is the **RotWord** and how do we apply it? Is it the same transformation in all rounds?

I can deduct *(from the result on slide 17)* that the **RotWord** transformation has done a shift upwards by 1 on the word:

```
+----+                 +----+ 
| 09 |                 | CF | 
+----+                 +----+ 
| CF |                 | 4F |  
+----+ --- RotWord --> +----+ 
| 4F |                 | 3C |
+----+                 +----+
| 3C |                 | 09 |
+----+                 +----+
```

Is my assumption of this transformation correct?
If so, will the amount shifted by change every round or does it remain constant?

Comment: Yes. See also en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard. There is a pseudo-code in NIST's AES standard document. I have a Python code that very closely follows that pseudo-code in s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7385224/1/

Comment: @Mok-KongShen: if this is an answer, please submit it as an answer (so that it can be accepted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See also en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard. There is a pseudo-code in NIST's AES standard document which is very helpful for implementors. I have a Python code that very closely follows that pseudo-code in s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/7385224/1/. For details of the design of AES, see J. Daemen, V. Rijmen, The Design of Rijndael. (Springer-Verlag, 2002)

Answer (score -1):

Sorted by:

Highest score (default)
2

Yes. See also en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard. There is a pseudo-code in NIST's AES standard document which is very helpful for implementors. I have a Python code that very closely follows that pseudo-code in s13

Comment: This is just copy past of [the comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/3912/mok-kong-shen) without indication of any reference.